# i have 2 regions , in 2 regions there are 2 cities. i have to output the count and name of cities. how can i get it

Tags: pymongo

{'_id': ObjectId('619f4e58b1a936e640635e97'), 'OrderDate': '01-01-2020', 'Region': 'East', 'City': 'Boston', 'Category': 'Bars', 'Product': 'Carrot', 'Quantity': '33', 'UnitPrice': '1.77', 'TotalPrice': 58.0, '': 'Sum of TotalPrice'}

{'_id': ObjectId('619f4e58b1a936e640635e98'), 'OrderDate': '04-01-2020', 'Region': 'East', 'City': 'Boston', 'Category': 'Crackers', 'Product': 'Whole Wheat', 'Quantity': '87', 'UnitPrice': '3.49', 'TotalPrice': 303.0, '': '17988.66'}

{'_id': ObjectId('619f4e58b1a936e640635e99'), 'OrderDate': '07-01-2020', 'Region': 'West', 'City': 'Los Angeles', 'Category': 'Cookies', 'Product': 'Chocolate Chip', 'Quantity': '58', 'UnitPrice': '1.87', 'TotalPrice': 108.46, '': '15336.92'}

{'_id': ObjectId('619f4e58b1a936e640635e9a'), 'OrderDate': '10-01-2020', 'Region': 'East', 'City': 'New York', 'Category': 'Cookies', 'Product': 'Chocolate Chip', 'Quantity': '82', 'UnitPrice': '1.87', 'TotalPrice': 153.34, '': '33325.58'}

{'_id': ObjectId('619f4e58b1a936e640635e9b'), 'OrderDate': '13-01-2020', 'Region': 'East', 'City': 'Boston', 'Category': 'Cookies', 'Product': 'Arrowroot', 'Quantity': '38', 'UnitPrice': '2.18', 'TotalPrice': 82.84}

{'_id': ObjectId('619f4e58b1a936e640635e9c'), 'OrderDate': '16-01-2020', 'Region': 'East', 'City': 'Boston', 'Category': 'Bars', 'Product': 'Carrot', 'Quantity': '54', 'UnitPrice': '1.77', 'TotalPrice': 95.58}

{'_id': ObjectId('619f4e58b1a936e640635e9d'), 'OrderDate': '19-01-2020', 'Region': 'East', 'City': 'Boston', 'Category': 'Crackers', 'Product': 'Whole Wheat', 'Quantity': '149', 'UnitPrice': '3.49', 'TotalPrice': 520.01}

{'_id': ObjectId('619f4e58b1a936e640635e9e'), 'OrderDate': '22-01-2020', 'Region': 'West', 'City': 'Los Angeles', 'Category': 'Bars', 'Product': 'Carrot', 'Quantity': '51', 'UnitPrice': '1.77', 'TotalPrice': 90.27}

```
w=db.sales.count_documents({"Region":"West"})
e=db.sales.count_documents({"Region":"East"})
print("Total count of orders in East region and West region are",w,"and",e)
a=db.sales.aggregate([{"$project":{"Region":1,"City":1}}])
for i in a:
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, Refer https://mongoplayground.net/p/d4L-QQXh1Id

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "Region": "$Region",
        "City": "$City"
      },
      "Total Amount": {
        "$sum": "$TotalPrice"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "Cities": "$_id.City",
      "Total Count": "$count",
      "Total Amount": "$Total Amount"
    }
  }
])
```